# Node.JS multi-d array of 'user' data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a web app that uses socket.io and connects to a node script.

When a page loads, I send the company identifier and user id to the node script. 
In that script, I have a 'users_connected' variable, on connect, I increment that var, then on disconnect I decrease it.

This gives me an overall user's connected count, BUT if a user has multiple tabs open, that number increments per tab.

I would then also like to keep a count per company, so I think I have two options:
- a multi-d array
- using a DB

For 3 months of the year, I have on average 400-500 users connected during the day.

A big array - that might not be very memory friendly.
But it also seems like a lot of excess DB io?

What do you suggest?

Comment: Save data in a file.

Comment: Thanks Armin, can you please provide a basic example?

Comment: For the multiple tabs problem I suggest setting a boolean flag on sessionStorage/localStorage. If the origin is the same, the flag can be accessed from multiple tabs.